# Chart with events by month from a series of dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts, time-series

I have a spreadsheet on google drive with a series of dates in a column, each date representing a particular event.

```
1998-01-07
1998-01-10
1998-01-22
1998-01-23
```

If I have two or more events on the same date, that date appear that many times in the column

```
2000-02-18
2000-03-12
2000-03-12
2000-03-12
2000-03-20
```

I'm trying to create a column chart with number of events by month without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should prepare your data to be plotted.

One of many ways is to use QUERY.

Example:

`=query(A1:A9,"select year(A),month(A)+1, count(A) group by year(A),month(A)+1 label year(A) 'Year', month(A)+1 'Month', count(A) 'Count'")`

NOTE: `month(A)+1` is used because 0 is January, 1 February and so on, but people use 1 for January, 2 for February and so on.

Result

```
Year  Month Count 
1998      1     4
2000      2     1
2000      3     4
```

Then you could create a chart like the following:

[image]

Comment: Looking at the chart, versus the data, the chart is nonsensical.  You wouldnt want the month as a Y-axis value.

Comment: Hi, I'm a newcomer to Google Sheets and SQL both, so I am curious about this.[`=query()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) looks like it is specific to the Google Visualization API. Is this normally all it is used for? Or is it just a query language that happens to be/is conveniently available within Sheets so it is used for other things besides preparing visualizations? Thanks.